# How to iterate elements from class and test parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms and I want to get the text of an inputfield which parent match a specific id.

Here is my code, the variable winner must point to the text in the inputfield. The inputfield and the button have both the same parent 'form' which has a specific id (67).

html:

```
<form name='form' id='67' method='post'>
   Winner: <input type='text' class='nameWinner' placeholder='name winner'>
   <input type='submit' class='getWinner'>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(".winnaarAanduiden").click(function() {
   var duel_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");
   var winner = "unknown";

$(".nameWinner").each(function() {
   if($(this).parent().attr("id") == $duel_id) winner = $(this).val();
});
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is m syntax incorrect?

Comment: Your variable is named `duel_id` but your equality check is against `$duel_id`. It should be `$(this).parent().attr("id") === duel_id`

Comment: Yes.  `$dualid` does not exist, and while `dualid` does, it is local to the function it has been created in.  Similarly, `winner` is local to the function it is created in, though you then create a global `winner` in the other function.

Comment: What's the code supposed to do? What is it doing that differs from your expectations? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: In first function your variable is called `duel_id` and in second `$duel_id`

Comment: Thank you Behrang, this is the wright answer. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to check the id, try

```
$(".winnaarAanduiden").click(function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var winner = $form.find('.nameWinner').val() || "unknown";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".winnaarAanduiden").click(function() {
   var duel_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");
   var winner = $('#' + duel_id).find('.nameWinner')[0].innerText;
}
```